# Get posts by category

Tags: wordpress

I want to get several post by categoriy. So I try to use get_posts() function:

```
<?php $args = array(
    'numberposts' => '3',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'orderby' => 'DESC'
    'category' => '91'
);


$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);?>

<?php echo get_the_date('F j, Y',$recent_posts["ID"])?>
```

But it doesn't work. How can I get posts by categoriy?

Answer (score 0):

you could create an `if` statement for fetching posts from a particulair category.

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'post' ,
  'orderby' => 'date' ,
  'order' => 'DESC' ,
  'posts_per_page' => 6,
  'cat'         => '3',
  'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
  'post_parent' => $parent
); 
$q = new WP_Query($args);
if ( $q->have_posts() ) { 
  while ( $q->have_posts() ) {
    $q->the_post();
    // your loop
  }
}
```

`cat => '3'` is the `category_id` so you should look up the `category_id` you want to fetch and put it into the `array`

Hope this helps!